# Change color/syntax highlighting for JSF/Facelets EL expressions in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, syntax-highlighting, facelets, el

I have installed both plugins: WTP and JBoss Tools (3.3) for Eclipse Indigo, but could not found a way to configure special syntax highlighting for EL expression in JSF (.xhmtl Facelets views).

The EL expressions they look like other html-attributes, but I want they have special highlighting (highlighted with other color for all #{...} expressions), so one can easier understand what are being rendered and navigate through the code faster.

Does anyone know, is it possible in Eclipse. I know, that with IntelliJ IDEA one can do it, but in my company I must use Eclipse.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse

Comment: i already know about this plugin Eclipse Color Themes, thats not what i want. I have configured all the syntax-highlight colors myself for different editors. My problem is, JSP/JSF editor does not have separate color settings HTML-attributes and JSP/JSF EL-expressions, therefor they are highlighted like each other, that's i dont want.

Comment: The JSP/JSF Editor of IntelliJ IDEA has different semantic highlighting-colors for different things: HTML-attributes, Tag-attributes, EL-expressions etc. Eclipse is still so dumm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in Eclipse, at least of Eclipse Indigo 3.7 and WTP 3.3. It is also not possible using JBoss Tools yet, presumably because it uses the WTP editors under the hood.

I suppose it would be worth looking at [Eclipse bug no. 298884](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298884), for there is mention of needing EL syntax coloring of expression tokens within a JSF page. Needless to say, the bug hasn't been fixed yet, and there hasn't been any activity for quite some time.

Comment: You might want to ask if there has been progress in this regard, in some other bug. Also, don't forget to vote on the bug.