# Change color/syntax highlighting for JSF/Facelets EL expressions in Eclipse Mars.2

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I found this question here on Stackoverflow: [Change color/syntax highlighting for JSF/Facelets EL expressions in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656687/change-color-syntax-highlighting-for-jsf-facelets-el-expressions-in-eclipse)

This question is 6 years old now.

Today I've tried to change the color for the stuff like that ${....} but I don't find any options in the preferences of Eclipse.

My question is now, is there still no options to change this kind of stuff or maybe I have tomatoes on my eyes ;-)

Thank you for your help =)

[image: This is what I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: This doesn't look like normal eclipse, does it?]
You can (probably) change the color settings on any new eclipse. I personally have Eclipse Neon, but I used to have Mars, and it worked there as well (If it doesn't, just download Eclipse Neon. It's free and all your work will be saved anyways.). This is the path I took:
Click on Window --> Click on Preferences --> Click on Java--> Click on Editor --> Click on Property Files Editor.
Ta-da!!! Now you can change all the things you want to change. The reason my screen is black is because I downloaded the "Dark" theme on my computer. I hope it works on yours! Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I am asking for.

I am asking for the Expression Language and there are no options in Eclipse to change the color.

I mean stuff like ${....}

I will add a picture of it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad!

Comment: I've added a picture ;-) And you will see I am already using the dark theme. Its better for the eyes, I guess :D

Comment: Oh, that is in another section. Do you want me to post an answer about that,too?

Comment: Sure if you have the correct answer and you tested it ;-)

Comment: Try it this time. I think it actually will work. (And if you find it does, please help me increase my measly reputation) :P

Comment: Sorry, but I think you don't have test it yourself. It is not Java self.

This is a JavaServerPage File (JSP File) so the syntax for this is not Java ;-) JSPs are HTML/XHTML/XML Files with JavaCode or in this case with Java Expression Language. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/ ... So, I can't upvote this answer. Sorry about this.

Comment: Oh... Then I don't know how to do this. Sorry :(